# Nested iteration over JSON using groovy closure in REST-assured

Tags: groovy, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following JSON response for my REST endpoint:

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "startRow": 0,
    "endRow": 1,
    "totalRows": 1,
    "next": "",
    "data": {
      "id": "workflow-1",
      "name": "SampleWorkflow",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "task-0",
          "name": "AWX",
          "triggered_by": ["task-5"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-1",
          "name": "BrainStorming",
          "triggered_by": ["task-2", "task-5"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-2",
          "name": "OnHold",
          "triggered_by": ["task-0", "task-4", "task-7", "task-8", "task9"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-3",
          "name": "InvestigateSuggestions",
          "triggered_by": ["task-6"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-4",
          "name": "Mistral",
          "triggered_by": ["task-3"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-5",
          "name": "Ansible",
          "triggered_by": ["task-3"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-6",
          "name": "Integration",
          "triggered_by": []
        },
        {
          "id": "task-7",
          "name": "Tower",
          "triggered_by": ["task-5"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-8",
          "name": "Camunda",
          "triggered_by": ["task-3"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-9",
          "name": "HungOnMistral",
          "triggered_by": ["task-0", "task-7"]
        },
        {
          "id": "task-10",
          "name": "MistralIsChosen",
          "triggered_by": ["task-1"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using rest-assured with a groovy gpath expression for an extraction as follows:

```
given()
.when()
.get("http://localhost:8080/workflow-1")
.then()
.extract()
.path("response.data.tasks.findAll{ it.triggered_by.contains('task-3') }.name")
```

which correctly gives me `[Mistral, Ansible, Camunda]`

What I am trying to achieve is to find the task names that are triggered by the `InvestigateSuggestions` task. But I don't know for sure that the taskId I have to pass in to `contains()` is `task-3`; I only know its name i.e. `InvestigateSuggestions`. So I attempt to do:

```
given()
.when()
.get("http://localhost:8080/workflow-1")
.then()
.extract()
.path("response.data.tasks.findAll{ 
    it.triggered_by.contains(response.data.tasks.find{
    it.name.equals('InvestigateSuggestions')}.id) }.name")
```

which does not work and complains that the parameter "response" was used but not defined.

How do I iterate over the outer collection from inside the findAll closure to find the correct `id` to pass into `contains()` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a dirty secret, the `restAssuredJsonRootObject`. This is undocumented (and subject to change although it has never change as far as I can remember in the 7 year+ lifespan of REST Assured).

This would allow you to write:

```
given()
.when()
.get("http://localhost:8080/workflow-1")
.then()
.extract()
.path("response.data.tasks.findAll{ 
    it.triggered_by.contains(restAssuredJsonRootObject.response.data.tasks.find{
    it.name.equals('InvestigateSuggestions')}.id) }.name")
```

If you don't want to use this "hack" then you need to do something similar to what [Michael Easter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704/michael-easter) proposed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130839/398441).

When it comes to generating matchers based on the response body the story is better. See docs [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#use-the-response-to-verify-other-parts-of-the-response).

Comment: Thanks very much. I had already looked through the rest-assured sources and found that. It worked too. Just didnt want to use something not supposed to be public in case it changed later and wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I should probably make this official since it's very handy. It'll probably not be called "restAssuredJsonRootPath" though but I'll try to be backward compatible if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is idiomatic but one approach is to find the `id` first and then substitute into another query:

```
@Test
void testCase1() {
    def json = given()
    .when()
    .get("http://localhost:5151/egg_minimal/stacko.json")

    // e.g. id = 'task-3' for name 'InvestigateSuggestions'

    def id = json
    .then()
    .extract()
    .path("response.data.tasks.find { it.name == 'InvestigateSuggestions' }.id")

    // e.g. tasks have name 'task-3'

    def tasks = json
    .then()
    .extract()
    .path("response.data.tasks.findAll{ it.triggered_by.contains('${id}') }.name")

    assertEquals(['Mistral', 'Ansible', 'Camunda'], tasks)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work. I just wanted to see if there was some way to do it within the groovy closure itself.