# Assertion value not matching for a field in body

Tags: api, google-places-api

I was hitting the google place search API while doing a POC in RestAssured.

Below is the response that I got. I am writing an assertion to match the value of 'lat' under 'location'.

The assertion that I have tried is as follows -

**body("obj.candidates[0].geometry.location.lat",equalTo("-33.8599358"));**

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "140 George St, The Rocks NSW 2000, Australia",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": -33.8599358,
                    "lng": 151.2090295
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": -33.85824767010727,
                        "lng": 151.2102470798928
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": -33.86094732989272,
                        "lng": 151.2075474201073
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "Museum of Contemporary Art Australia",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": false
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 2736,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108440264878062594882/photos\">Kun-Lin Tsou</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA1K9W8-AwTJ953e-cj2DdF0bhf5uVpnHcmBoSF4Cz5rlEjkODupFUCeGuim6Ryx4j0-jKU-jnpYch1xWV4UfWxbZZhzoXBuY8opP9gVZ_Z03mMyPa71lzYRAf5gAWX4bpEhAcia7kO56eCSu6x7IRSTTBGhTQK4-BGWyFhpvUZESi3axcejZP_Q",
                    "width": 3648
                }
            ],
            "rating": 4.4
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

But I am getting error as below when I run the program -

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path obj.candidates[0].geometry.location.lat doesn't match.
Expected: -33.8599358
  Actual: null**

When I run the request using postman, I am getting valid response as above and also with valid data against it. I am not understanding that why when assertion is checked it is getting 'Null' value against actual result field.

Can anyone help me in identifying the issue in here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the field using jsonpath in response:

```
assertThat(response.jsonpath().get("candidates[0].geometry.location.lat"), equalTo("-33.8599358"));
```

If you get an Exception of deserialization put jackson-databind in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that exception because there is no field by the name `obj` in your response. Just remove `obj` from your path expression and use `candidates[0].geometry.location.lat`

From the looks of it, I believe you were trying to refer to the "root" of the json payload using `obj`. If so, then know that you dont need to. In REST-assured, the path expression is always *relative* to the root anyway. But just in case you need to, you *can* refer to the root of the json in REST-assured using `restAssuredJsonRootObject` although this is not public. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138340/8882940) from Johan, the founder and author of REST-assured.